# Debug Ruby 1.9 in Emacs using the "debugger" gem

Tags: ruby, emacs

I am using the **debugger** gem to debug my code writing in Ruby 1.9 on Windows. How do I integrate it in Emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know about Emacs dbgr?

https://github.com/rocky/emacs-dbgr

It has built-in capabilities for ruby-debug, including the .el source files, and could be a good starting point for you.